# How to load alternative strings.xml from resources programmatically

Tags: android, localization

I want to provide three different langauges. The default language is english so all my string values in the `values` folder are in enlish. I created two other folders

- values-de for the german language
- values-cn for the chinese language

each folder contains a `strings.xml` file where i defined the values in german for the de folder and in chinese for the cn folder.

My question now is: **How can i load a different language programmatically** because i want to provide buttons in my app interface where the user can switch the language. The settings of the device wont be editable for our users. Our users can just see the app itself and nothing else so i have to provide the language switching from within my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the configuration at runtime

Do this in `onCreate` of the activity

```
String languageToUse  = "de"; // The language you want to change
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToUse); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Yes this works in the oncreate method. but how can i update the language outside the oncreate. for example after a button click without recreating the whole activity?

Comment: You have to recreate the activity if you want the changes to be applied. Or you need to reset the values of each  `TextView` `Button` etc.

Comment: wow... a restart of the activity just to change the language using resources... maybe it is better to store all values in one strings.xml and change them all manually.

Comment: You can try one thing. Just a wild guess. Use this code on button click and reload the values of views (don't restart the activity)